# Named and unnamed functions in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, function

What is the nature of the data structure used to store the name of a function in JavaScript?

In other words, where is the string "Foo" (i.e. the name of the function `Foo`) stored when this code is evaluated?

```
function Foo() {}
```

Also, do anonymous functions have a hidden name?

Answer (score 1):

*where is the string "Foo" (i.e. the name of the function Foo) stored*

In the global scope.

You can avoid this by using a [self invoking anonymous function](http://esbueno.noahstokes.com/post/77292606977/self-executing-anonymous-functions-or-how-to-write) :

```
(function() {
    alert('Hello World');
})();
```

, or by associating a var to a function within a local scope :

```
function myBigFunction() {
var myfunction = function foo(){alert('Hello World');};
}
```

No hidden name.

Comment: Okay, I know this. I am considering whether there is something akin to an execution context (i.e. a data structure internal to the interpreter) that holds function metadata?

Comment: @Ben if there is it is not part of the accessible api, afaik, and would be dependent to the particular interpreter.